# How to remove duplicate child from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

i need help about how to remove one or more array child from set of array that have exactly same keys and values with other child in PHP. Please take a look this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 10:35
            [scn_to_tm] => 12:55
            [mov_prnt_nm] => Thor Ragnarok
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 10:40
            [scn_to_tm] => 12:39
            [mov_prnt_nm] => Geostorm
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 11:30
            [scn_to_tm] => 13:22
            [mov_prnt_nm] => One Fine Day
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 11:30
            [scn_to_tm] => 13:22
            [mov_prnt_nm] => One Fine Day
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 11:30
            [scn_to_tm] => 13:00
            [mov_prnt_nm] => Total Chaos
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [scn_fr_tm] => 11:30
            [scn_to_tm] => 13:22
            [mov_prnt_nm] => One Fine Day
        )
)
```

as you can see from above array, i want to remove array[3] and array[5] from array because it has duplicate keys and values with array[2]. Above array created dynamically, so please don't ask me to use `unset(array[3])` and `unset(array[5])`.

here is my array creation code, the array created from other array:

```
foreach ($datas as $data)
{
    if (array_key_exists('attr', $data))
    {
        $arr[] = array(
            'scn_fr_tm'     => substr_replace($data['attr'][0]['scn_fr_tm'],':',2,0),
            'scn_to_tm'     => substr_replace($data['attr'][0]['scn_to_tm'],':',2,0),
            'mov_prnt_nm'   => substr($data['mov_prnt_nm'], 0, 20)
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: could be done in the array creation code, but you dont show that so ..

Comment: Thanks @nogad, i had edit my question

Comment: i would create an array to just hold titles as you build the new array, then you can use a simple in_array() check before adding to your main array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of a couple of different options:

```
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));
```

or

```
while ($item = array_pop($array)) {
    if (!in_array($item, $array)) {
        $unique[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You know, as far as the `in_array` one, you can do as @nogad suggested in the comments and just check for that before adding each item into the array as you build it. That should be a bit more efficient that trying to make it unique afterward.